# Cascade updates to all foreign keys without actually changing the primary key

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, cascade

I need to design a way for people to invite an existing user (who belongs to organization A) to organization B and go ahead and set up what permissions they will have in organization B once they accept the invitation.  The permissions are implemented as foreign keys to the user id from various tables.

My idea is to create a "proxy" user with a different id, and people can grant permissions to the proxy user.  Then when the real user accepts the invite, I would update all the foreign keys from the proxy user id to the real user id.

I'm wishing I could just `UPDATE "Users" SET id = :realUserId WHERE id = :proxyUserId` to take advantage of `ON UPDATE CASCADE` clauses of all my `FOREIGN KEY` constraints.  But obviously that would cause a primary key conflict since `:realUserId` already exists.

I don't suppose there's any reasonable way to make Postgres to perform the cascading updates to all tables with foreign keys to `Users`, without updating `Users` itself?

Comment: Why don't you use regular users for invitations and mark them as invited?

Comment: basically because it would be a large code change to our APIs to deny those users access based upon an `invitationAccepted = false`.  Though maybe still better, it turns out

Comment: and actually, also, some granular permissions don't go through our organization memberships table, so using an `invitationAccepted` flag to the organization membership row would add a lot of joins to those permissions checks